# How to setup a library for python2 not python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I have python2 and python3 on linux

when I tried to setup as for example `route53` library using
`pip install route53`
or `python -m pip install route53`
it told me that `Requirement already satisfied: route53 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages (1.0.1)`

[image]

so I want to install `route53`for python2 not python3.
Thank you!

Comment: `pip2 install python route53` should work

Answer (score 0):

### Consider creating an alias for python2

### Step 1: locate where python2 is located

```sh
$ which python2
```

the output will probably be something like

```sh
/usr/bin/python2
```

### Step 2: create an alias for python2

```sh
alias python=/usr/bin/python2
```

Now you can install packages by issuing python like so

```sh
$ python -m pip install route53
```

Comment: ``$python -m pip install route53
/usr/bin/python2: No module named pip
``

Comment: try: sudo apt install python2-pip